# Pasar datos de un DATAGRIDVIEW a unos textbox

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando en c#, y tengo datos en un GRIDVIEW quiero saber si es posible que al momento de selecionar la fila se llenen los textbox de manera autimatica o si hay alguna otra de hacerlo?

Comment: si que se puede. podrías mostrar lo que has intentado? para saber por donde vas y poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Conozco una manera, es útil y bastante sencilla, primero que nada, involucra dos eventos:

- `dataGridView1_CellClick`
- `dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick`

El primer método hace que cuando selecciones una fila, cual sea (dando clic sobre ella) se almacene el indice de la fila (`RowIndex`), seria asi

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        renglon = e.RowIndex; //La variable renglon debe estar previamente declarada y ser de tipo entero
    }
```

Una ves que tienes el indice de la fila que esta seleccionada solo extraes los datos del `dataGridView`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string nombre;

        nombre = dataGridView1.Rows[renglon_selec].Cells["NOMBRE"].Value.ToString();
        txtNombre.Text = nombre; //Aqui le asignas al TextBox lo que sacaste del dgv
    }
```

Para los demas campos solo tienes que ir haciendo lo mismo.

Si te sirvió no olvides marcarla :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar el atributo **onrowcommand** a tu GridView y obtener los valores con el **GridViewCommandEventArgs** que recibe el evento [como referencia puedes tomar las respuestas de una pregunta que se hizo hace tiempo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254880/how-to-get-row-data-by-clicking-a-button-in-a-row-in-an-asp-net-gridview)

Cuando obtengas el valor que necesites se lo puedes asignar al TextBox utilizando su atributo **runat="server"** que se le agrega para poder hacer referencia desde tu código de C#